# Sound stop from another ViewController?

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

Hello everyone i have a question why my sound don't stop when i click the button from another Controller

**FirstController:**

```
- (IBAction)touchBtnA:(id)sender {
[self.settings setEnabled:NO];



if (enabledA) {
    [self.BtnA setEnabled:NO];
    [self.BtnB setEnabled:YES];


    enabledA = NO;
    enabledB = YES;
    [self.BtnA setAlpha:1.0];
    [self.BtnB setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [_downButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DownButon@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_upButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButonUpDown.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else {
    [self.BtnA setEnabled:NO];
    [self.BtnB setEnabled:YES];
    enabledA = NO;
    enabledB = YES;
    [self.BtnB setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.BtnA setAlpha:1.0];
    [_upButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButonUpDown.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}


 NSUserDefaults *standartDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


if ([standartDefaults stringForKey:@"editSelected"]) {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    int timeToAdd = [[defaults objectForKey:@"addTime"]intValue];

    _remainingTimeA += timeToAdd;
    [self updateTime:A];
}else{

}





if (_remainingTimeB < 601) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/secundamer.wav",[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]]];
    NSError *error;
    _milescundsSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    _milescundsSound.numberOfLoops = 1;

    [_milescundsSound play];
    [_clockSound stop];
}else{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/clock.wav",[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]]];
    NSError *error;
    _clockSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    _clockSound.numberOfLoops = -1;

    [_clockSound play];
    [_milescundsSound stop];

}



NSURL *urlButton = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/buttonSound.wav",[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]]];


 NSError *error;

buttonSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:urlButton error:&error];
buttonSound.numberOfLoops = 0;

[buttonSound play];
```

}
I use sound in IBAction and i need to stop sound from another ViewController.

**SecondController:**

```
- (IBAction)actionSoundMute:(id)sender {
if ([sender isSelected]) {
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ВКЛ.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    [sender setSelected:NO];
}else{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ВЫКЛ.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [timer.clockSound stop];
    [timer.milescundsSound stop];
    [sender setSelected:YES];


}

}
```

If someone could help me with this problem.Thanks.

Comment: Prove that `timer` really is a reference to the view controller whose `clockSound` is playing the sound. For example, `timer` might be nil, in which case those `stop` commands do nothing. Prove to me that it is not nil, please. Or it might be a reference to some _other_ FirstController instance. Prove to me that that is not the case. Show me how `timer` gets set, and use NSLog to prove that it is set correctly.

Comment: Shou more codes about timer in your firstviewcontroller,and how do you get reference of this timer in second viewcontroller

Comment: I use this sound in IBAction.